# Loki and the C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-loki

I have a few questions about the library Loki and also the new standard C++11.

My first question is about the `LevelMutex` functionality of the library.
`LevelMutex` directly uses a `CRITICAL_SECTION` on windows and a `pthread_mutex_t` in
Linux in order the implement the functionalities. The classes are extremely well
design but a question remains in my head. Now that we have a brand new wrapper
in the new standard (`std::mutex`) is it worth replacing the low level objects
that are platform dependent by this one ? If not, why ? My point is that
- we can remove lots of compiler check in Loki
- we can keep an up to date version of Loki and all changes will be pushed to Loki when changes occur in the standard library
- we can use the exceptions of `std::mutex` in Loki.

I know that `std::mutex` is just a wrapper around the platforms mutex objects and
that the exceptions are also a wrapper around the system specific errors but still ...
The same question applies for the functionalities in `Threads.h`.

My second question is about the `SmartPtr` implemented in Loki.
Do you think it is worth using this implementation given the fact that we have
`shared_ptr`, `unique_ptr`, etc ? If so why ? If not, I think it a good idea to rewrite
the LockingPtr implementation a little bit to get a thread safe shared_ptr ?

My last question is about the new `std::thread` functionality in the C++11 standard.
I am thinking of writing policy classes for this particular functionality like
having the ability to create joinable threads or detachable threads.
In your opinion, what part of `std::thread` would be interesting to create a policy for ?

Thanks in advance for the answers !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a broad and somewhat subjective topic and I can only give you my personal advice. I won't go into details as I think it's important to take a step back and look at the bigger picture.

I made some good experience by using the new C++11 standard and replacing other libraries by whatever the standard library offers. And by "me", I also mean the code base of where I work (a department of a company with more than 100.000 employees).

Libraries like Loki or Boost have done a pretty good job of exploring new frontiers and bringing C++ forward, for Boost it was actually an explicit goal to create new components which would eventually be standardized.

While the standardized versions of `std::shared_ptr`, `std::thread` and `std::mutex` might lack a few details, they are well designed, portable and, given that they are part of the standard library shipping with the compiler, they are very well tested! These are important points in favor of them. It also helps to make your code future proof and easier to maintain, it's easier for new people to jump in.

My advice would thus be this: Use everything C++11 (including the standard library) has to offer as much as possible. Only use Loki, Boost or other libraries if necessary but keep your mind open by following their development.

Comment: I get your point and this is exactly why I asked this question, I always try to use what is stable and tested. So to your opinion it is not a bad thing to make some modifications in Loki to get it working WITH the new (and tested) features.

Comment: @Athanase Basically yes, although I would check if it can be integrated into Loki or if the additional layers are thin enough to build your own version. Maintaining your own fork of Loki might create a few problems and getting rid of dependencies is usually helpful for stability. Consider writing those parts from Loki that you need from scratch, using the standard library as much as possible. Also, consider using `std::shared_ptr` et. al. directly. Loki's PBD sounds great but in the end I like `std::shared_ptr` much better in practice.

Comment: I have looked a lot at the sources of Loki since I have known the library from Alexendrescu's book. It is totally doable and I  will start working on it ASAP. Also, I asked the question because I have heard a lot of people saying "Why use std::thread if it is just a wrapper around pthread, why use std::vector if it is just a wrapper around C arrays, that just adds function calls which drop the performances". But I personally think that this (very little) cost is far out classed by the benefit of a library like Loki (and the standard lib of course).